# How to add background-image and linear gradient Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Want to add the below background-image css property, both link of the image and linear-gradient  through JQuery . even just the link is not working for me

```
.product-video-container {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../Images/chicago.jpg");
}
```

my attempt is this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".product-video-section .product-video-container").each(function () {
    var _self = this;
    $('.product-video-container',_self).css('background-image', './Images/chicago.jpg')
  });
})
```

Comment: $('.dnow-video-container').css('background-image','url("/Images/chicago.jpg")'); You wont need _self in selector.

Comment: Or why not $('.dnow-video-container').addClass("product-video-container");

Comment: the image link will come from the back end,so  have to put the image url in the js, also i need to put the linear gradient there also @HastaTamang. doing self due to multiple components with same classes but with different images would be on a page.

Comment: Can you post your html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
$('.product-video-container', this).css...
```

is the equivalent of:

```
$(this).find('.product-video-container').css...
```

ie looks for `.product-video-container` as a descendent of `this` - as `this` is already a `.product-video-container` it would mean your html would need to be:

```
<div class='product-video-section'>
  <div class='product-video-container'>
    <div class='product-video-container'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which seems unlikely.

Assuming you have:

```
<div class='product-video-section'>
  <div class='product-video-container'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Keeping the `.each` and `_self` which are used elsewhere in the app (unrelated code, but relevant for OP), you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".product-video-section .product-video-container").each(function () {
    var _self = this;
    $(_self).css('background-image', '../Images/chicago.jpg')
  });
})
```

(also changed to path `../Images/`)

Comment: i added this, because there will be multiple components like that on the same page with different images, but that's different story.

Comment: Updated: can see how you would need to use `this` in your actual code and removing it would confuse the issue.   The point of this answer is to highlight that you're actually doing `$(".-section .container .container")` which doesn't seem right, maybe it is as you've not included your html.  The selector in the each loop in the question code will not be finding anything.

Comment: ya i should have added the html too. but i got what you are saying

Answer (score 1):

When using multiple backgrounds, keep in mind that they are treated as a stack. The first property will be on top, and the second will be underneath it. In your example, the gradient will appear on top, and the image will appear on the bottom. Here's how you can implement a stacked background using the CSS method in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".background").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("../Images/chicago.jpg");
});
```

Change ".background" to be your class or use (this).find(.class) for multiple classes.

Comment: had to fix the " to ' on the link and missing )

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".product-video-section .product-video-container").each(function () {

     $('.product-video-container').css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), url("../Images/chicago.jpg")');
  });

  });
```

Comment: `.each` and then not using `this`?  What's the `.each` for?

Comment: No clue mate. Copied and pasted from OP, was in a hurry to post an answer first.. lol

Comment: that's fair enough :)